# How to write a template specialization of a type trait that works on a class template?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, type-traits

Let's consider the following [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) code, with the slight modification that the derived class has to be a template one:

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename T>
struct crtp_base {};

template<typename T>
struct derived : crtp_base<derived,T>  {};
```

I would like to define a type trait telling whether a class is derived from the CRTP base class. In other words, I need a type trait that works on a class template (and not on a type).

The first approach would be to define a generic version of the trait, with the peculiarity that the parameter is a template template one:

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED> 
struct is_crtp_based : std::false_type {};
```

Now, a first attempt for the template specialization of interest:

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename T>
struct is_crtp_based <crtp_base<DERIVED,T>> : std::true_type {};
```

but the compiler is not happy with this since it expects a class template but it finds a (non template) class `crtp_base<DERIVED,T>` instead.

**Question:** how should one write the specialization in such a case ? More generally, how to deal with type traits that take a class template as parameter ? I guess that there are already existing use cases like this but I don't find any of them right now.

Note: I can solve the question by the following trait that uses `std::is_base_of` :

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename T=void>
struct is_crtp_based : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_base_of_v<crtp_base<DERIVED,T>,DERIVED<T> >> {};

static_assert (is_crtp_based<derived>::value == true);
```

but I would like to understand how to correct my first incorrect attempt through template specialization.

**UPDATE:** For a little bit more context, the `crtp_base` needs to know the `T` type, which explains the `T` template parameter in its definition and makes all the remaining more difficult (see my comment to 463035818_is_not_an_ai's answer).

Comment: "templated type" is not a term. There are types and there are templates or "class templates"

Comment: That's right, just corrected.

Comment: well, it turns out your question is about just that misunderstanding.

Comment: Specialization of `is_crtp_based` for `crtp_base` won't match `derived`. Specializations don't respect inheritance. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: please post a [mcve] for your self written trait. I do not understand how you are planning to use it. The specialization is for types that are `crtp_base<DERIVED,T>`, but you want types that derive from it

Comment: why is the base not simply `template<class DERIVED>
struct crtp_base {};` ? And then derived can be `template<typename T> struct derived : crtp_base<derived<T>>  {};` ? I think somewhere earlier you jumped to the conclusion you'd need template template arguments and now everything is more complicated. But actually you do not need them. At least not everywhere. Not in the part this question is about.

Comment: with specialization, `derived<int>` can inherit from `crtp_base<derived,int>` whereas `derived<char>` won't inherit from any class, so what value `is_crtp_based<derived>` would be?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: yes it could be that way but in order  to make the example simpler, I didn't mentioned that I need to know type ```T``` in the ```crtp_base``` class. If I directly provide ```derived<T>``` as parameter to ```crtp_base```, it guess that it will be not so easy to know ```T``` only from ```derived<T>```.

Comment: @edrezen I knew you would say that ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dare to claim that what you actually want is this:

```
template<typename DERIVED>
struct crtp_base {};

template<typename T>
struct derived : crtp_base<derived<T>>  {};
```

To check whether a type derives from an instantiation of `crtp_base` you can use

```
template <typename T>
using is_crtp = std::is_base_of<crtp_base<T>,T>;
```

And thats it.

---

No need for complicated template template arguments.

---

You want `T` to be available in the crtp base? Ok, write a trait for that:

```
template <typename T> 
struct get_T;

template <template <typename> class X,typename T>
struct get_T<X<T>> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Now `get_T< derived<T>>::type` is `T`. In your base you can use `get_T<DERIVED>`. There is a template template argument, but only in one place, not all over your code.

Note that the `get_T` is rather limited, it only works for templates with a single type argument. Though tahts exactly the same limitation as in your version of `crtp_base`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Actually, I perfectly know the difference between a type and a class template. The funny part is that I indeed started with the simpler definition the base with ```template<typename DERIVED> struct crtp_base {};``` but since I needed to have the ```T``` type in this class, I was trapped by the CRTP because I tried to reuse in the base a type defined in the derived class, somehow an egg/chicken problem that made the compiler unhappy. But with the ```get_T``` helper, it seems to work. Well done !

Comment: As a matter of fact, my initial CRTP issue with this simpler definition of ```crtp_base``` and the need to have the ```T``` type defined in this class would worth a post by itself... Using an external helper such as ```get_T``` seems to postpone some analysis by the compiller which makes it possible to decently define ```derived``` from ```crtp_base``` without this egg/chicken problem.

Comment: @edrezen In my comments merely pointed out the issue in your trait and its specialization.  Your `is_crtp_based` trait is a trait for template, then you try to specialize it for a type `is_crtp_based <crtp_base<DERIVED,T>>` thats not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

Primary templates and specializations have template arguments that are a different kind of thing.

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED> 
struct is_crtp_based;
```

in the primary template, you are saying what the category of arguments are.  Here, we are passing not a type but a template as its one argument.

```
is_crtp_based <crtp_base<DERIVED,T>>
```

and here, you are passing a *type* to `is_crtp_based`!

You need to think of templates classes as a different kind of thing than types.

```
template<class T> struct foo;
```

`foo` is a template class, a **factory** of types.  `foo<int>` is a type.  They have a relationship similar to types and variables, but 1 level of abstraction higher.

```
int
```

is a type

```
int x;
```

is a variable of type `int`.

```
foo
```

is a template class

```
foo<int>
```

is a type instantiation of the template class.

In your case, you want to pass a **type** to

```
template<template<typename> class DERIVED> 
struct is_crtp_based;
```

so the primary template needs to take a type:

```
template<class T> 
struct is_crtp_based:std::false_type{};
```

we'll derive the trait from `false_type` - by default, it stuff doesn't qualify.

Now to handle the actual thing

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct is_crtp_based<Z<Ts...>>:std::true_type{};
```

we probably aren't detecting what you want, but this matches **types** against being a template instantiation, where that template takes only types.

So

```
is_crtp_based<foo<int>>
```

that is truthy.

Now, in your case, you want to mess around with base types.  A problem is that template traits do not inspect the base type!  Examining base types is a property of inheritance, and inheritance lookups happen with template function selection during overload resolution, not in trait classes.

So we'll have to start over and do this with template functions, then use the result and make a trait.

We'll start with a C-style variardic function.  We do this because it has a really low priority for selection during overload resolution:

```
constexpr std::false_type is_crtp_based_ptr(...) { return {}; }
```

then we pattern match:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class...Ts>
constexpr std::true_type is_crtp_based_ptr( T const volatile*, Z<T, Ts...> const volatile* ) { return {}; }
```

so far so good.  For this case:

```
template<class D, class...Ts>
struct base {};
struct derived: base<derived, Ts...> {};
```

we can check:

```
is_crtp_based_ptr( (derived*)0, (derived*)0 )
```

and it should return `true_type` if I wrote it right.

This doesn't match your funny template restriction case, but we can augment:

```
template<template<class...>class X, class... Xs, template<template<class...>class, class...>class B, class...Ts>
constexpr std::true_type is_crtp_based_ptr( X<Xs...>* derived, B<X, Ts...>* base ) { return {}; }
```

which should catch:

```
template<template<class>class D, class...Ts>
struct base {};
template<class T>
struct derived: base<derived, T> {};
```

similarly.

I will, however, seriously doubt that you want to pass the template and not the type to your CRTP base.

Answer (score 3):

Your starting point for `is_crtp_based` is too complicated. A simple solution is to just use some instance of the template to test the inheritance on a specific type:

```cpp
template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename T>
struct crtp_base {};

template<typename T>
struct derived : crtp_base<derived,T>  {};

template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename TestOn = int> 
struct is_crtp_based : std::is_base_of<crtp_base<DERIVED, TestOn>, DERIVED<TestOn> > {};

template<template<typename> class DERIVED, typename TestOn = int>
constexpr bool is_crtp_based_v = is_crtp_based<DERIVED, TestOn>::value;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7bK39a7fY

Comment: Indeed, I don't know why I used ```std::integral_constant``` in my (working) solution. I'm afraid it comes from some inglorious copy/paste...